# Google Compute Engine VM instance stuck in staging

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I'm just starting out with Google Cloud, and I have a single VM instance in zone europe-west2-c.

This morning, I promoted the VM's IP address from ephemeral to static, and selected Start for the VM. Since then, the Status is showing a spinning wheel, I can't connect to the VM because it says "the status is stopped", the options Start/Resume, Stop, Suspend and Reset options on the hamburger menu are all greyed out. Clicking on View logs does not reveal any data.

If I mouse over the spinning wheel, it shows "The instance has been staged and will soon begin running".

That was over two hours ago, and I've now lost confidence that anything is going to happen without my intervening in some way. Does anyone have any idea what I do next?

[update: I've given up, deleted the VM and started again. But it would be nice to know what to do if the problem recurs]

Answer (score 1):

If the console isn't reponding you can try either different browser or even in incognito mode.

If you still see the same message try using `gcloud` utility:

`gcloud compute instances describe instance_name --zone=your-zone | grep status`

which will give you the state of the VM.

You can always try to start it right away:

`gcloud compute instances start instance_name --zone=us-your_zone`

You can always try stopping it first and then start it again (also using `gcloud`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was definitely in a state where it could neither be started nor stopped, probably because of some weird sequence in which I did the provisioning (I'm a newbie at this), so in the end, deleting it and starting again was easiest.